# flutter alarm clock not getting sound

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, local, alarm

I'm working currently on a flutter project

the app is working fine but i have some issues:

1-i get the notification but i don't get any sound from the notification, i don't know if this is flutter_local_notifications dependency problem because when i tried to update it to the latest version i got few errors from main page and alarm page

2-i can't access these options(Repeat,Sound,Title):

https://i.ibb.co/4fj7x16/s3.png

here is the alarm page:

```
      import 'package:clock_app/alarm_helper.dart';
      import 'package:clock_app/constants/theme_data.dart';
      import 'package:clock_app/data.dart';
      import 'package:clock_app/models/alarm_info.dart';
      import 'package:dotted_border/dotted_border.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
      import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

      import '../main.dart';

  class AlarmPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _AlarmPageState createState() => _AlarmPageState();
 }

 class _AlarmPageState extends State<AlarmPage> {
 DateTime _alarmTime;
 String _alarmTimeString;
 AlarmHelper _alarmHelper = AlarmHelper();
 Future<List<AlarmInfo>> _alarms;

 @override
 void initState() {
_alarmTime = DateTime.now();
_alarmHelper.initializeDatabase().then((value) {
  print('------database intialized');
  loadAlarms();
 });
 super.initState();
 }

void loadAlarms() {
_alarms = _alarmHelper.getAlarms();
if (mounted) setState(() {});
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 64),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Alarm',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'avenir',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            color: CustomColors.primaryTextColor,
            fontSize: 24),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<AlarmInfo>>(
          future: _alarms,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData)
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((alarm) {
                  var alarmTime =
                      DateFormat('hh:mm aa').format(alarm.alarmDateTime);
                  var gradientColor = GradientTemplate
                      .gradientTemplate[alarm.gradientColorIndex].colors;
                  return Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 32),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: gradientColor,
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: gradientColor.last.withOpacity(0.4),
                          blurRadius: 8,
                          spreadRadius: 2,
                          offset: Offset(4, 4),
                        ),
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.label,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 24,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 8),
                                Text(
                                  alarm.title,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontFamily: 'avenir'),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            Switch(
                              onChanged: (bool value) {},
                              value: true,
                              activeColor: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Mon-Fri',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'avenir'),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              alarmTime,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'avenir',
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              onPressed: () {
                                _alarmHelper.delete(alarm.id);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).followedBy([
                  if (alarms.length < 5)
                    DottedBorder(
                      strokeWidth: 2,
                      color: CustomColors.clockOutline,
                      borderType: BorderType.RRect,
                      radius: Radius.circular(24),
                      dashPattern: [5, 4],
                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: CustomColors.clockBG,
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24)),
                        ),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
                          onPressed: () {
                            _alarmTimeString =
                                DateFormat('HH:mm').format(DateTime.now());
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                              useRootNavigator: true,
                              context: context,
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                                  top: Radius.circular(24),
                                ),
                              ),
                              builder: (context) {
                                return StatefulBuilder(
                                  builder: (context, setModalState) {
                                    return Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          FlatButton(
                                            onPressed: () async {
                                              var selectedTime =
                                                  await showTimePicker(
                                                context: context,
                                                initialTime:
                                                    TimeOfDay.now(),
                                              );
                                              if (selectedTime != null) {
                                                final now = DateTime.now();
                                                var selectedDateTime =
                                                    DateTime(
                                                        now.year,
                                                        now.month,
                                                        now.day,
                                                        selectedTime.hour,
                                                        selectedTime
                                                            .minute);
                                                _alarmTime =
                                                    selectedDateTime;
                                                setModalState(() {
                                                  _alarmTimeString =
                                                      selectedTime
                                                          .toString();
                                                });
                                              }
                                            },
                                            child: Text(
                                              _alarmTimeString,
                                              style:
                                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text('Repeat'),
                                            trailing: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                          ),
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text('Sound'),
                                            trailing: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                          ),
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text('Title'),
                                            trailing: Icon(
                                                Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                                          ),
                                          FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                            onPressed: () async {
                                              DateTime
                                                  scheduleAlarmDateTime;
                                              if (_alarmTime
                                                  .isAfter(DateTime.now()))
                                                scheduleAlarmDateTime =
                                                    _alarmTime;
                                              else
                                                scheduleAlarmDateTime =
                                                    _alarmTime.add(
                                                        Duration(days: 1));

                                              var alarmInfo = AlarmInfo(
                                                alarmDateTime:
                                                    scheduleAlarmDateTime,
                                                gradientColorIndex:
                                                    alarms.length,
                                                title: 'alarm',
                                              );
                                              _alarmHelper
                                                  .insertAlarm(alarmInfo);
                                               scheduleAlarm(
                                                   scheduleAlarmDateTime);
                                            },
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.alarm),
                                            label: Text('Save'),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            );
                            // scheduleAlarm();
                          },
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/add_alarm.png',
                                scale: 1.5,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 8),
                              Text(
                                'Add Alarm',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontFamily: 'avenir'),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  else
                    Text('Only 5 alarms allowed!'),
                ]).toList(),
              );
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'Loading..',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            );
          },
          ),
         ),
       ],
      ),
    );
  }

      void scheduleAlarm(DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime) async {
      var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'alarm_notif',
      'alarm_notif',
     'Channel for Alarm notification',
      icon: 'logo',
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('a_long_cold_sting'),
      largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('logo'),
    );

    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(
    sound: 'a_long_cold_sting.wav',
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true,
    presentSound: true);
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
    0,
    'Office',
    'Good morning! Time for office.',
    scheduledNotificationDateTime,
    platformChannelSpecifics);
    }
    }
```

and here is the main page:

```
import 'package:clock_app/enums.dart';
import 'package:clock_app/models/menu_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'views/homepage.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

var initializationSettingsAndroid =
  AndroidInitializationSettings('logo');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
  requestAlertPermission: true,
  requestBadgePermission: true,
  requestSoundPermission: true,
  onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
      (int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {});
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
  initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
  onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
if (payload != null) {
  debugPrint('notification payload: ' + payload);
}
});
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
     ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider<MenuInfo>(
      create: (context) => MenuInfo(MenuType.clock),
      child: HomePage(),
      ),
     );
    }
  }
```

and the dependencies:

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+2
```

i am still learning and following a tutorial, so please if you know what is the problem and how to solve it explain to me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in flutter local notification, you can set the alarm to be insisted by setting extra flag 4, and thus keep the alarm repeat until user tap on it

for more detail [click here](https://andrious.medium.com/notification-alarms-in-flutter-25e3ee3c336e)